# Checking radio button when cell is clicked and changing the background of the cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to check a radio button when the mouse clicks anywhere within the cell, and also use this action to change the colour of the cell. When the radio button is unchecked the colour should go back to white.

My code is

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
  $(this).toggleClass('green', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```css
.green
{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But this does not help to achieve both the actions. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few little logical errors in your example:

1) `checked` is a **property**, not an attribute, so you should be using `.prop()` to set it (see guidance at https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

2) `$(this).is(":checked")` won't ever be true, because `this` represents the table cell, not the radio button

3) Regardless of point 2, it doesn't make any sense to test this value, because (if you check it correctly) you already know it's true due to the previous line of code. What you want to be doing is setting the class to green automatically, but also removing the "green" class from the other cells in the same row.

Here's a demo which achieves all that:

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("green");
  $(this).addClass('green');
});
```

```css
.green
{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks this works with other css settings too. Only when cells are dynamically created it does not seem to work?

Comment: for that you would have to change your event handler declaration. This kind of standard event handler will run once, and add the event to any matching elements it detects at that moment. See the section entitled "Direct and delegated event handlers" in https://api.jquery.com/on/ for how you can get round that and allow it to deal with newly created elements (effectively you set the handler on an element higher up the DOM which always exists, and then tell it a target selector within that to filter on). There are also numerous previous questions on StackOverflow which deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly to have the radio selected when you click anywhere in the cell wrap it in a `label` which has `display: block` set on it. Then you get the behaviour for free without needing any JS.

To set the background on the `td` which contain a checked radio, hook a `change` event handler to the radios themselves, then get the `closest()` `td` and call `addClass()` on it. `toggleClass()` isn't relevant here, as you can only select a radio, you can never de-select it. You can instead use `siblings()` to remove the `green` class from any other cells. Try this:

```js
$(':radio').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('td').addClass('green').siblings().removeClass('green');
});
```

```css
table label {
  display: block;
}

table td.green {
  background-color: #0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name1"></label></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name1"></label></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name1"></label></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name1"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name2"></label></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name2"></label></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name2"></label></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><label><input type="radio" name="name2"></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input:radio").change(function() {
  if($("input:radio").is(":checked")){
    $(this).parent("td").addClass("green").siblings("td").removeClass("green");
  }
  else{
    $(this).parent("td").removeClass("green").siblings("td").removeClass("green");
  }
  
});
```

```css
.green
{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
      <td style="width: 50px;"><input type="radio" name="name2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your jQuery code like this:

```
$("td").click(function() {
  $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("green");
  $(this).addClass("green");
});
```